# Docker image installation private network detailed instructions

Tags: stellar-core

I am able to install a stand alone network on an aws ec2 instance with the command

> docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v
>   "/home/scott/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart
>   --standalone

I then get the following after which docker does not respond.

> Starting Stellar Quickstart
>
> mode: persistent network: standalone (Standalone Network ; February
>   2017) postgres: config directory exists, skipping copy supervisor:
>   config directory exists, skipping copy stellar-core: config directory
>   exists, skipping copy horizon: config directory exists, skipping copy
>   postgres: already initialized core: already initialized Waiting for
>   postgres to be available... postgres: up init-core-scp: ok horizon:
>   already initialized postgres: down starting supervisor 2018-09-22
>   13:44:43,518 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
>   2018-09-22 13:44:43,527 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
>   2018-09-22 13:44:43,527 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without
>   any HTTP authentication checking 2018-09-22 13:44:43,528 INFO
>   supervisord started with pid 6 2018-09-22 13:44:44,530 INFO spawned:
>   'postgresql' with pid 53 2018-09-22 13:44:44,531 INFO spawned:
>   'stellar-core' with pid 54 2018-09-22 13:44:44,533 INFO spawned:
>   'horizon' with pid 55 2018-09-22 13:44:45,698 INFO success: postgresql
>   entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds
>   (startsecs) 2018-09-22 13:44:45,698 INFO success: stellar-core entered
>   RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
>   2018-09-22 13:44:45,698 INFO success: horizon entered RUNNING state,
>   process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

Which commands do I need to provide to configure the network?

It says command not found for all commands. How do I generate the seed account?

I would like to set up 3 separate nodes running on separate aws ec2 instances and connected to the same network.